# Understanding the odd behavior of this current loop transmitter

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

In my assignment, I want to study this current transmitter circuit shown in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnAjS.png). The goal of this circuit is to output a constant load current \$ i_L\$ (denoted by \$ I_L\$ in the diagram) controlled by \$ v_S\$ (operating within a certain range of \$ v_S\$ and \$ R_L\$).  I derived the expression for relating \$ v_S\$ and \$i_L\$; that expression is (see figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkNry.jpg))
$$\dfrac{i_L}{v_S}=-\dfrac{1}{R_2}$$
The circuit simulation can be found on Multisim online [here](https://www.multisim.com/content/okonwf97tVTXk5whCmmBTY/iim-hw03-q2-1/open/).

In the assignment question, the circuit is specified to work for $$|v_S|<1 V, R_L < 1k\Omega$$
However, the circuit does not behave according to the relation \$ i_L/v_S=-1/R_2\$ at those extreme conditions (being \$v_S=1 V, R_L = 1k\Omega\$), and it's probably because the op-amp output voltage \$ V_o\$ saturates at \$\pm \$15 V.
The expression that relates \$ V_o\$ with \$ v_S\$ and \$ R_L\$ is (see figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpkoS.jpg))
$$V_o = -(2 v_S \times R_L/R_2 + v_S)$$
And this must stay within saturation limits. At \$v_S=1 V, R_L = 1k\Omega,  V_o=-21\$ V, so that explains the odd behavior there.
My concern is that, **for a value of \$ V_o\$ within limits, specified by some \$ v_S\$ and \$ R_L\$ pair, the output is still anomalous**. For example, when \$ v_S=0.8 V\$ and \$ R_L=300 \Omega\$, \$ V_o=-5.6 V\$, but simulated \$i_L=-5.66\$ mA as opposed to being -8 mA, and I can't think of any reason why we're deviating from the expected results.
[image: The current transmitter circuit schematic.]

[image: Derivation relating v_S and i_L.]

[image: Deriving relation between V_o, R_L and v_S.]

Answer (score 3):

I did a simulation Dynamic DC Analysis with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip) and a old 741.

Here is what I get ... EE&O, 10 < R5 < 10k (log stepping *2).

[image]

For another configuration of resistors (1 k)

[image]

And here is a Maple sheet ... for analytical results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both the results you cited are correct. The 1k results show a voltage out that's below the negative rail, but that's the simulator's fault. I think your problem is that you aren't considering RL's effect on the positive feedback voltage. In both cases IL is -10*Vs ma.